# Test A SSH Connection from Windows commandline

Tags: windows, ssh, networking, plink, scripting

I am looking for a way to test if a SSH server is available from a Windows host.  I [found](http://gnuwhatimsaying.com/test-an-ssh-connection/) this one-liner, but it requires the a Unix/Linux host:

```
ssh -q -o "BatchMode=yes" user@host "echo 2>&1" && echo "UP" || echo "DOWN"
```

Telnet'ing to port 22 works, but that's not really scriptable.  I have also played around with [Plink](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink), but I haven't found a way to get the functionality of the one-liner above.

Does anyone know Plink enough to make this work?  Are there any other windows based tools that would work?

*Please note that the SSH servers in question are behind a corporate firewall and are NOT internet accessible.*

---

Arrrg.  Figured it out:

```
C:\>plink -batch -v user@host
Looking up host "host"
Connecting to 10.10.10.10 port 22
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.62
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.7p1-hpn12v17_q1.217
Using SSH protocol version 2
Server supports delayed compression; will try this later
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 1024 aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
Using username "user".
Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL
Attempting GSSAPI authentication
GSSAPI authentication initialised
GSSAPI authentication initialised
GSSAPI authentication loop finished OK
Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
Disconnected: Unable to authenticate

C:\>
```

Comment: If ssh is up on a windows host the output should be about the same.  What makes you think that Windows would handle the protocol differently?

Answer (score 1):

Putty has a command line mode. Probably would work, but I'm not positive.

You could also use Nmap to check if the port is accepting connections.